# how to add case statement you create in a left join and a CONCAT

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi i am trying to join two concatenated fields here from two different tables.

i am trying to join the S table with code and market with the SM table with a code and market

the S table has a few markets that dont match so i created a case statement as shown below so i can join the S market field and the S advertiser code field.
which is not working.

getting this error 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Invalid column name 'SET Market'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Invalid column name 'SET Market'.

```
SELECT dISTINCT SM.[Region]
      ,SM.[Market]
      ,SM.[PA]
      ,SM.[Advertiser]
      ,SM.[AdvertiserCode]
      ,CONCAT(SM.[advertisercode],SM.[market]) as [smdashadcode+market]
      ,S.[Actuals vs projections]
      ,S.[Year]
      ,S.[Month]
      ,S.[Area]
      ,CASE S.[Market]
            WHEN 'Twin Cities' THEN 'Minneapolis - St. Paul'
            WHEN 'Fort Myers'  THEN 'FT. MYERS - NAPLES'
            WHEN 'Bowling Green' THEN 'Nashville'
            WHEN 'North Miss' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Monroe, LA' THEN 'Monroe' 
            WHEN 'Southern Miss-Hattiesburg/Laurel/Meridian' THEN 'SOUTHERN MISS'
            WHEN 'Northern Miss-Columbus/Tupelo' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Little Rock, AR' THEN 'LITTLE ROCK'
        ELSE S.[Market] END AS [SET Market]

      ,S.[Zone Type]
      ,S.[Category]
      ,S.[Subcategory]
      ,S.[Event]
      ,S.[Network]
      ,S.[AE]
      ,S.[Client]
      ,S.[ClientID]
      ,S.[# Spots]
      ,S.[Gross ($)]
      ,CONCAT(S.[CLIENTID],[SET Market]) AS [SETClientID+Market]

  FROM [MAIN].[dbo].[CET Sports] S
  LEFT JOIN [MAIN].[dbo].[Data] SM
         ON CONCAT(S.[CLIENTID],S.[SET Market]) = CONCAT(SM.[advertisercode],SM.[market])
```

expecting results to be

S Market    sm market    sm advetiser    SM AE
Nashville    nashville   IDEA            SOFIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `[SET Market]` like you do in the `ON..` statement. 
What you can do is use in its place the CASE statement that creates this column:

```
ON CONCAT(S.[CLIENTID], CASE S.[Market]
            WHEN 'Twin Cities' THEN 'Minneapolis - St. Paul'
            WHEN 'Fort Myers'  THEN 'FT. MYERS - NAPLES'
            WHEN 'Bowling Green' THEN 'Nashville'
            WHEN 'North Miss' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Monroe, LA' THEN 'Monroe' 
            WHEN 'Southern Miss-Hattiesburg/Laurel/Meridian' THEN 'SOUTHERN MISS'
            WHEN 'Northern Miss-Columbus/Tupelo' THEN 'TUPELO'
            WHEN 'Little Rock, AR' THEN 'LITTLE ROCK'
        ELSE S.[Market] END) = CONCAT(SM.[advertisercode],SM.[market])
```

Comment: thanks that worked!

question though how i still have some NULLs after the join

is there any way for me to join on other concats on top of the advertiser code and market?.  i am trying to get as less nulls as i can.

Comment: added but any ways you can answer my question above

Comment: You need to add sample data and expected results and mention which values shouldn't be nulls.

Comment: Try changing the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.